# How to get template of std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I've wrote a simple metaprogramm that checks whether 2 templates are the same. Here it is:

```cpp
template<template<class...> class _Tp, template<class...> class _Up> 
struct is_same_template : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class _Tp> 
struct is_same_template<_Tp, _Tp> : std::true_type {};
```

And it works (but not with std::array)

```cpp
is_same_template<std::vector, std::vector>::value // 1
is_same_template<std::map, std::map>::value       // 1
is_same_template<std::vector, std::map>::value    // 0

is_same_template<std::vector, std::array>::value  // Error: type/value mismatch at argument 2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either compare types:

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2> struct is_same_template: std::false_type {};

template<template<class, std::size_t> struct StdArray,
         class T1, std::size_t n1, class T2, std::size_t n2>
struct is_same_template<StdArray<T1, n1>, StdArray<T2, n2>>: std::true_type {};
```

or define a separate comparator per each template signature:

```cpp
template<template<class, std::size_t, class...> class T1,
         template<class, std::size_t, class...> class T2>
struct is_same_template_T1_n1: std::false_type {};

template<> struct is_same_template_T1_n1<std::array, std::array>: std::true_type {};
```

In general, there's no common template interface that would equally accept type- and non type-parameters.